# scroll() doesn't work in meteor autorun

Tags: jquery, meteor

scroll() doesn't work when the template appears, but it works once if server restart (by update code) or if I run the code in chrome console.

```
Template.chatBubble.onRendered(function() {
Tracker.autorun(function () {
 if(Session.get('chatBubble')){
  $('.textArea').scroll(function() {
  console.log('is scrolling');
 }
});});
```

html

```
{{#if isChatbubble}}
{{> chatBubble}}
{{/if}
```

p.s I use scroll to pagination. Thank you so much

Comment: Yikes! You're binding a scroll event every time the `chatBubble` session variable changes. Could you elaborate in your post what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
$('.textArea').scroll(function() {
  console.log('is scrolling');
 }
},0);
```